# Filtering dict to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have problem with filtering dict to dataframe

I have dataframe:

| location | recipient | material | type | colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_GR | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_BL | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_WH | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_TP | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_GLASS | bin | green |
| store | bottle | ZN_GLASS_GR | bin | green |
| store | bottle | ZN_GLASS_BL | bin | green |
| store | bottle | ZN_GLASS_WR | bin | green |
| store | bottle | ZN_GLASS_TP | bin | green |

Create dataframes by category of material:

```
plastic = data.loc[data['material'].str.contains('PLASTIC') == True]              
glass = data.loc[data['material'].str.contains('GLASS') == True]
```

Create a dict for types of plastic:

```
plastic_dict = {}
for klass in plastic['material'].unique():
    plastic_dict[klass] = plastic[plastic['material'].str.contains(klass)]
```

Display:

```
plastic_dict.keys()
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['ZN_PLASTIC', 'ZN_PLASTIC_GR', 'ZN_PLASTIC_BL', 'ZN_PLASTIC_WH', 'ZN_PLASTIC_TP'])
```

Create a dict for types of glass:

```
glass_dict = {}
for klass in glass['material'].unique():
    glass_dict[klass] = glass[glass['material'].str.contains(klass)]
```

Display:

```
glass_dict.keys()
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['ZN_GLASS', 'ZN_GLASS_GR', 'ZN_GLASS_BL', 'ZN_GLASS_WH', 'ZN_GLASS_TP'])
```

Now, I'm trying to filter some data using the dict and create a dataframe:

```
ac_plastic_ = {}
for i in plastic_dict.keys():
    locals()[f"ac_plastic_{i}"] = plastic_dict[i]
    locals()[f"ac_plastic_{i}"].to_csv (r'ac_plastic_' + str(i) + '.txt', index = None, header=False, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

But the filter fail and I have the following:

```
display(ac_plastic_ZN_PLASTIC)
```

Output:

| location | recipient | material | type | colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_GR | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_BL | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_WH | bin | red |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_TP | bin | red |

For the more specific sentence the filter works:

```
display(ac_plastic_ZN_PLASTIC_GR)
```

Output:

| location | recipient | material | type | colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store | bottle | ZN_PLASTIC_GR | bin | red |

I have tried to fix unsuccessfully.
So, how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Please post minimal code, minimal and sufficient explanation and most of all minimal reproducible example

Comment: This is a 'please do my homework question'. How about posting an attempt at the solution using the complete code you are using

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are using [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) when you create the dictionary:

```
glass_dict = {}
for klass in glass['material'].unique():
    glass_dict[klass] = glass[glass['material'].str.contains(klass)]
```

Therefore you obtain all rows that contain `ZN_PLASTIC` in the `string`, what you need to do is match the exact `klass`:

```
plastic_dict = {}
for klass in plastic['material'].unique():
    plastic_dict[klass] = plastic.loc[plastic['material'] == klass]
```

**Note:** Always use `loc` or `iloc` to select the rows when you create partial `dataframes`, otherwise later you might get some errors related to slices or copies when trying to apply other functions.